# graphs in latex

Tags: diagrams, picture-mode

I am trying to build some kind of a tree, but in its node instead of a symbol I want to put a framebox. Also, in that framebox at a specific position I want an other framebox. While I couldn't find a way to use the tree structure that exists in latex in order to do so, I started putting frameboxes at the positions that I wanted. Thus, I built the following, but now I don't know how too draw a line that connects each bi to the s.

```
\begin{figure}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.06in}
\centering

\begin{picture}(70,50)

\put(25,35){\framebox(14,10){\Large server} }
\put(0,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 1}}
\put(25,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 2}}
\put(50,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 3}}
\put(30.5,35){\framebox(3,3){s}}
\put(5.5,12){\framebox(3,3){$b_1$}}
\put(30.5,12){\framebox(3,3){$b_2$}}
\put(55.5,12) {\framebox(3,3){$b_3$}}

\end{picture}   
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Switch to the tikz ecosystem immediately, the picture env is not worth spending time on. It even have cool libraries for drawing trees

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

[image]

with `forest` and using nodes' labels is simple:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\tikzset{every label/.append style = {draw, inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
    draw,
    text width=22mm, minimum height=16mm,
    font=\Large,
    text centered,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    %
    l sep=8mm,
    s sep=6mm,
            }
[server, label={[anchor=south]below:s}
    [browser 1, label={[anchor=north]:$b_1$}]
    [browser 2, label={[anchor=north]:$b_2$}]
    [browser 3, label={[anchor=north]:$b_3$}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With `pict2e` you can easily draw segments specifying their end points.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\setlength{\unitlength}{0.06in}
\centering

\begin{picture}(70,50)
\put(25,35){\framebox(14,10){\Large server} }
\put(0,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 1}}
\put(25,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 2}}
\put(50,5){\framebox(14,10){\Large browser 3}}
\put(30.5,35){\framebox(3,3){s}}
\put(5.5,12){\framebox(3,3){$b_1$}}
\put(30.5,12){\framebox(3,3){$b_2$}}
\put(55.5,12) {\framebox(3,3){$b_3$}}
\Line(7,15)(32,35)
\Line(32,15)(32,35)
\Line(57,15)(32,35)
\end{picture}   

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I was looking for.  It works perfect.